# How to fix this - The website does not supply identity information

Tags: http, web

[image]

I am getting this kind of problem in all the website, I did.
Am I missing any code in HTML, which is causing this problem. Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like some plugin / addon to me. https everywhere or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity Information is only available through encrypted(secure) connections, you need to pay to get SSL Certificates (https). If you have it, just add 's' like so -> https://...